# Effect of wording on outcome of referendum

Tags: referendum

In this [famous episode of "Yes, Prime Minister"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahgjEjJkZks), Sir Humphrey explains how it is possible to get two opposite results to the same opinion poll, by changing the wording and the framing. I would like to know to what extent this phoenomenon exists in referendums? My guess is that in a referendum it would be quite minor, since voters would spend more time in deciding what to vote, and not be influenced by framing effects.

I understand that it is hard to get data on this, as most referendums are done once, using the same framing, to all voters (there are no "A/B tests"). But maybe someone has found a methodology to test this question empirically: what is the potential effect of wording on the outcomes of a referendum?

Comment: A common feature of this is whether a question should be framed as Yes/No, and if so which side gets "Yes".  For example between "Should the UK remain in the EU" or "Should the UK leave the EU".   Which is why the final ballot didn't have "Yes/No" but "Leave/Remain".  -- Yes, framing issues may be very significant.

Comment: Here is a reference: https://academic.oup.com/book/32964/chapter-abstract/278100197?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @JamesK thanks, the reference is very interesting. But, it considers hypothetical referendums. There are two reasons to believe a real referendum would be different. (a) Real referendum has real consequences, so people have more incentive to think what outcome is better for them. (b) In real referendums, there are massive campaings for both sides, including e.g. massive ads saying "vote Yes" or "vote No". Voters may be influenced by these campaigns, so when they arrive at the voting booth, they do not need to read the information - they already know what they are going to vote.

Comment: The Grauniad says that "11% of voters make up their mind on the day". But the other 89% will also have been exposed to the question througut the campaign, so a poorly framed or leading question is likely to a consequential effect on the 89% too. https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2019/jun/04/post-election-research-shows-11-of-voters-made-up-their-mind-on-polling-day  And, of course people may understand the question, but not the consequences.  The campaigns will have been <s>lying</s>pushing their own interpretations of the question.

Comment: But you're probably right, it probably has a greater effect on an opinion poll than on a referendum. But of course, it doesn't much matter if an opinion poll makes a "wrong" decision.

Comment: Wording definitely matters and is a hot subject of litigation and lobbying, but I'm not sure how this would be quantified as ballot issue language is so case specific and there are a nearly infinite number of possible wordings.

Comment: FWIW after the failed 1995 Quebec secession referendum, the Canadian Feds successfully got a rule specifying that future referendums would have to clearly frame that the intent was to secede from Canada (as opposed to say homilies about "Quebec being special").  That push was fought tooth and nail by the Bloc Quebecois IIRC.  So both parties considered the effect real enough.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarity_Act

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The majority opinion among political scientists appear to be that the
wording does not matter that much (*framing* is a different
matter). At least not in a typical Western context, where most
referendums are posed as yes/no questions and where referendums are
held at most once every few years and preceeded by lengthy public
debate.

Rocher and Lecours tackles this question - "Does the wording of a
referendum question matter?" - in the book [The Routledge Handbook to
Referendums and Direct Democracy](https://www.routledge.com/The-Routledge-Handbook-to-Referendums-and-Direct-Democracy/Morel-Qvortrup/p/book/9780367462017). They conclude:

> The case studies discussed above suggest that paying attention to
> the clarity of a referendum question might be of limited benefit for
> at least three reasons. The first is that the nature of the
> referendum question can be a reflection of complex, sometimes
> long-standing, constitutional preferences, which may not be
> simplified easily. [...] The second reason is that the meaning of
> the question is provided, to a very large extent, by the political
> debate that surrounds the path towards the referendum campaign, as
> well as the campaign itself. [...] The third reason why attention
> paid to the clarity of a referendum question might have limited
> benefits is that even when the question is very short and apparently
> straightforward, debate about the meaning of its key terms, such as
> independence, cannot (and probably should not) be avoided. [...]

> In the end, the voters will decide based on their understanding of
> the political issue on which they must take a stand. The wording of
> the question turns out to be relatively secondary.

Political science professor Matt Qvortrup echoes the sentiment in a
[BBC interview about Brexit](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-32899104):

> He says the question is not vitally important because people will
> know before they enter the polling place what their views are on
> Europe.

> He says: "The overall conclusion one can draw if one looks around
> the world is that question itself extremely rarely has an impact on
> the outcome of the referendum."

One of the more confusing referendum questions in recent years came
from the [2015 Greek bailout referendum](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-33311422):

> Should the plan of agreement, which was submitted by the European
> Commission, the European Central Bank and the International Monetary
> Fund in the Eurogroup of 25.06.2015 and is comprised of two parts
> that constitute their unified proposal be accepted?

> The first document is entitled “Reforms For The Completion Of The
> Current Program And Beyond” and the second “Preliminary Debt
> Sustainability Analysis.”

But it appears that the Greeks understood the question well-enough
and, as far as I can tell, the result has not been challenged on
grounds of the question being confusing. The referendum question for
the 1998 Good Friday agreement was quite confusing too - "Do you
support the Agreement reached at the multi-party talks on Northern
Ireland and set out in Command Paper 3883?" - but in the end, it
didn't matter much.

So while you can find hundreds examples of politicians concerning
themselves about exact wordings on referendums, their worries are
probably unfounded.

Polls, on the other hand, are well-known to be susceptible to wording
choices. And perhaps you can make the argument that wording matters
(much) more on multiple choice or ranking questions.

Comment: But even if the exact wording may not matter much, wouldn't the given alternatives and the timing in a yes/no referendum matter a lot? It's not like a multitude of possible Brexit referenda are done every other week, but there was exactly one at a specific time about specific choices.